# onClick getElementByID(field).value=x for input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to clear a field from a form. Right now it's being reset to the default value but I want to clear it so it has either no value or a space as value.

PHP is writing this code.

```
<script>
function resetInput() 
 {
  var x=\"\";
  document.getElementById(\"playerName\").value=x;
 }
</script>

<form name=\"input\" action=\"search.php\" method=\"get\">
<input id=\"playerName\" class=searchField type=\"text\" name=\"playerName\" value=\"".$_GET['playerName']."\">
<input type=\"submit\" class=searchBut value=\"Search\">
<input onclick=\"resetInput()\" type=\"reset\" class=searchBut value=\"Clear\">

</form>
```

And I also tried :

```
  document.getElementById(\"playerName\").innerHTML=x;
```

I removed the other inputs from this form but there is other inputs and I want the reset button to reset all input to default value and clear the playerName input.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Why the hell are you escaping the quotes ?

Comment: Why you are using `\"`?

Comment: It's in php I just pasted the inside of what is going to be echoed.

Comment: @Satpal....as OP said  PHP is writing this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button type is "reset", its default action is to reset form to default values. So what is happening - in `onclick` value of `playerName` is reset to "" and then default "reset" action kicks in resetting all the fields including `playerName` to default.

Since you do want to reset the rest of the fields to default values - you should keep default "reset" action. All you need to do is make function `resetInput` run *after* default action. One way to do it is on a small timeout:

```
<input onclick=\"setTimeout(resetInput,10)\" type=\"reset\" class=searchBut value=\"Clear\">
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I had tried this but with window.setInterval(resetInput(), 500), but it didn't work.  Thanks a lot.